# Bash parameter expansion in brackets not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am writing a script that wraps the find command to search for specific source file types under a given directory. A sample invocation would be :

```
./find_them.sh --java --flex --xml dir1
```

The above command would search for .java, .as and .xml files under dir1.

To do this manually I came up with the following find command :

```
find dir1 -type f -a \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.as" -o -name "*.xml" \)
```

As I am doing this in a script where I want to be able specify different file sets to search for you end up with the following structure :

```
find_cmd_file_sets=$(decode_file_sets) # Assume this creates a string with the file sets e.g. -name "*.java" -o -name "*.as" etc
dirs=$(get_search_dirs) # assume this gives you the list of dirs to search, defaulting to the current directory

for dir in $dirs 
do
    find $dir -type f -a \( $find_cmd_file_sets \)
done
```

The above script doesn't behave as expected, you execute the script and the find command churns for a while before returning no results.
I'm certain the equivalents of `decode_file_sets` and `get_search_dirs` I've created are generating the correct results.

A simpler example if to execute the following directly in a bash shell

```
file_sets=' -name "*.java" -o -name "*.as" '
find dir -type f -a \( $file_sets \) # Returns no result
# Executing result of below command directly in the shell returns correct result
echo find dir -type f -a \\\( $file_sets \\\)
```

I don't understand why variable expansion in brackets of the find command would change the result. If it makes any difference I am using git-bash under Windows.

This is really frustrating. Any help would be much appreciated. Most importantly I would like to understand why the variable expansion of `$file_sets` is behaving as it is.

Comment: Why do you believe that quotes in a variable are the same as quotes at the command line?

Comment: I don't know what would make you think I believe that. I am using single quotes so the double quotes in the variable should be preserved when used as an argument to find

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in the for loop -- it should be ***for dir in $dirs***

Comment: @ahjmorton The double quotes stored in a parameter are not used to quote `*.java`; they are treated literally. You cannot nest syntactic quotes like this. `bash` arrays were introduced for precisely this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Don't use quotes in `find_cmd_file_sets` variable and disable pathname expansion (`set -f`) before calling `find`.

When you have "special" character in a variable content and then you try to expand that variable without quotes than bash will surround each word with "special" character with single quotes, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
VAR='abc "def"'
echo $VAR
```

The output is:

```
+ VAR='abc "def"'
+ echo abc '"def"'
abc "def"
```

As you can see, bash surrounded `"def"` with single quotes. In your case, the call to `find` command becomes:

```
find ... -name '"*.java"' ...
```

So it tries to find files which start with `"` and end with `.java"`

To prevent that behavior, the only thing you can do (which I'm aware of) is to use double quotes when expanding the variable, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
VAR='abc "def"'
echo "$VAR"
```

The output is:

```
+ VAR='abc "def"'
+ echo 'abc "def"'
abc "def"
```

The only problem, as you probably noticed already, is that now the whole variable is in quotes and is treated as single argument. So this won't work in your `find` command.

The only option left is to not use quotes, neither in variable content nor when expanding the variable. But then, of course, you have a problem with pathname expansion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
VAR='abc *.java'
echo $VAR
```

The output is:

```
+ VAR='abc *.java'
+ echo abc file1.java file2.java
abc file1.java file2.java
```

Fortunately you can disable pathname expansion using `set -f`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
VAR='abc *.java'
set -f
echo $VAR
```

The output is:

```
+ VAR='abc *.java'
+ set -f
+ echo abc '*.java'
abc *.java
```

To sum up, the following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern='-name *.java'
dir="my_project"
set -f
find "$dir" -type f -a \( $pattern \)
```

Comment: Accepting this as it is the most complete description of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work, Its tested on bash.

```
file_sets=' -name "*.java" -o -name "*.as" '
command=`echo "find $dir -type f -a \( $file_sets \)"`

eval $command
```

Comment: This approach does work, would like to know why the original version did not behave as expected

Comment: Don't know exactly but in my opinion or atleast what i concluded is due to find command functionality which take everything as its argument and not replacing variable to its value. considering variable as its argument to -a option.

Comment: The `echo` in a command subsitution is redundant; `command="find $dir -type -f -a \( $file_sets \)"` works as well.

Comment: When possible, avoid the use of `eval`--and it's almost always possible.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` arrays were introduced to allow this kind of nested quoting:

```
file_sets=( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.as" )
find dir -type f -a \( "${file_sets[@]}" \)
```